# Restrict Android app to very specific resolutions and screen sizes

Tags: android, android-manifest, dpi, android-screen-support, pixel-density

In my app I plan to support only few specific screen sizes and resolutions, here they are:

[image]

How can I restrict my app to be able to be installed only on these screens? Is it something in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, or Developer Console, or both?

Answer (score 1):

you can apply by add flags in manifest.xml file :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html
And you can restrict by :
    You should use this attribute in your mainfest  `android:largestWidthLimitDp="enter mobile pixel value which above you want restrict."`